# Arduino Leonardo on Android

Tags: android, keyboard, arduino, hid

I have a small Android board (APC 8750) that I am busy writing an app for. As part of the project, I require a small device that will be able to send "P" and "N" key-presses to flip through a PDF document. I have decided to try and use a [Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo) to do so.

The problem is: When using any of the Arduino keyboard examples, the APC does not seem to recognize any of the key-presses. I have also tried this with another Android board I found lying around the office, and it still didn't work.

The weird thing is that the mouse examples all work on the APC.

I'm wondering if the Arduino keyboard library maybe isn't "generic" enough, and if there is some way of making it so.

I should also mention that I have tested the APC with a variety of keyboards, and they all worked fine.

Comment: Does the leonardo-keyboard work when plugged into a normal computer?

Comment: Yes, it does work on my PC